# If the line tangent to the graph of $f(x)=e^{3x^2}$ at the point $(a,f(a))$ is parallel to the line $y=3x-5$, then what is the value of $a$?

Tags: calculus

> If the line tangent to the graph of $f(x)=e^{3x^2}$ at the point $(a,f(a))$ is parallel to the line $y=3x-5$, then what is the value of $a$?

I know that the tangent line has a slope of $3$.

Working with the equation of the given curve, we have:

$$f(x)=e^{3x^2}\\f'(x)=e^{3x^2}\cdot 6x$$

Since we know the slope of the tangent is $3$, we substitute:

$$3=f'(a)=e^{3a^2}\cdot 6a\\\implies\frac{1}{2}=ae^{3a^2}$$

This is where I am stuck. I have tried taking the natural logarithm of both sides, but the variable is on different levels. I searched around online and the closest I have to an answer is a [Ask Dr. Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209014354/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68497.html) where an iterative method is needed like Newton's method.

This is supposed to be just a problem in an AP Calculus AB class, so I was under the assumption that there was an analytic solution.

Comment: Just wondering, is this a problem from a textbook or is it made up by your school? This cannot be solved analytically.

Comment: Made up by the teacher @imranfat

Comment: I kind of thought so. Are there any other instructions? Looks like the only way out is a numerical method

Comment: Well we can write $$\frac{1}{2}=af(a)$$so if we knew $f(a)$ then we'd be in good shape. Is there anything in the question about $f(a)$, such as $f$ intersects $y=3x-5$ at $a$ or something?

Comment: No other instructions. I typed it verbatim. There are a few other problems that are similar that I also cannot find the answer to due to having variables at different levels. I suspect that the teacher might have forgot chain rule and made too difficult a problem. @imranfat

Comment: If there is no other information given as Dave indicated, then I think only approximations will work, though I can hardly imagine that this would satisfy the mind

Comment: We can use the Lambert W function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. However, this is likely beyond high school math, and probably not where the teacher wanted this problem to go.

Comment: Dang! The Lambert W function looks super cool! I agree with you that this is not where the problem was expected to go. @Dave

Comment: Isn't it important that students realize that there are many simple problems that do not submit to simple analytical techniques?? ie. $\cos(x)-x=0$. Plot $\frac{1}{2a}$ and $e^{3a^2}$ on the same axes and find the intersection. Most calculators can do this nowadays. The AP Calculus Exam has an analytical MC section and a numerical MC section.

Comment: Just contacted the teacher. Apparently this was for a later unit where we can use graphing Calculators. I plugged in $3$ into one function and $6xe^{3x^2}$ into the other function to get [this graph](https://i.imgur.com/q0XxT0G.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the Lambert W function:

\begin{align} 
2a\exp(3a^2)&=1
,\\
4a^2\exp(6a^2)&=1
,\\
6a^2\exp(6a^2)&=\tfrac32
,\\
\operatorname{W}(6a^2\exp(6a^2))&=\operatorname{W}(\tfrac32)
,\\
6a^2&=\operatorname{W}(\tfrac23)
.
\end{align}

Since $\tfrac32>0$, there is 
only one real value of the right hand side, 
$\operatorname{W_0}(\tfrac32)$.

The answer then is

\begin{align} 
a=\sqrt{\tfrac16\operatorname{W_0}(\tfrac32)}
\approx0.3478173
.
\end{align}
.
[image]